# R how to pass variable into a function inside tapply

Tags: r, tapply

Now my code is as follows:

```
common_timestamps = NULL
tapply(data$timestamps, data$date, 

     function(x, common_timestamps ) { 
          if(length(common_timestamps ) == 0) {
            common_timestamps = x 
          } else {
            date_time = intersect(common_timestamps, x)
          }
          return(common_timestamps)
       }, 
      common_timestamps
)
```

I want to get the common timestamps from the code in the above. I found each time in the loop, the common_timestamp is null and it did not return common_timestamp. What is wrong with code? I think my concept about passing
variables into function for R language might be right.

Could you correct my error and explain my error?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Can you post some sample `data` so it is easier to get an idea what are you trying to do and what is a problem?

But my idea is that maybe instead of `common_timestamps = x` you want to use `common_timestamps <<- x` so you assign x to a variable outside of a tapply?

I am pretty sure you do not change global common_timestamps but a parameter of a function, which is a copy of global `common_timestamps`. And returning `common_timestamps` does not change anything, because you do not assign a result of tapply anywhere. But even if you do, you cannot use it before whole tapply ends.

Comment: My intention is to pass the variable common_timestamps into the tapply() function. Assign all the common stamps into the passed variable common_timestamps in the tapply() function. finally when tapply() finish, it returns the variable timestamps.

Comment: This is not like this that tapply works, it will return one value per group

Comment: Are you sure it's not the `union` function you want? If serially applied to a vector it seems that `intersect` is not going to deliver much of value.

Comment: In the above code, I would like to pass the variable common_timestamps into the tapply() function. Assign new value to this variable. After the tapply finish, this variable can hold the new valued assigned inside the tapply() function and be used in the remaining code. I put a code inside tapply() to test the value of common_timestamp, I found each time the value of common_timestamp is NULL. I would like to common_timestamp to hold the common timestamps in the data which contain measurements in four days. Could anyone give a clue about my problem?